# Python csv comparison using reader

Tags: python, csv

i tried this script to compare two csv files..

```
   import csv
   file1 = open("1.csv", "r")
   reader1=csv.reader(file1)
   reader1.next()
   file2 = open("2.csv", "r")
   reader2=csv.reader(file2)
   reader2.next()
   file3 = open("file3.txt", "w")
   file4 = open("file4.txt", "w")
   file1.seek(0,0)
   file2.seek(0,0)
   list1 = file1.readlines()
   list2 = file2.readlines()
   for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i == j:
            file3.write(i)
            file3.write(j)
        else :
            file4.write(i)
            file4.write(j)
    continue
```

in the output i am getting with headers included and plus the mismatched files are repeating.  for eg:if my 1.csv contains

```
Name    Salary   
A   20000
B   15000
C       10000
```

2.csv contains

```
Name    Salary
A   40000
D   10000
B   15000
C       9000
```

output should be

```
file3: B 15000 B 15000

file4: A 20000 A 40000
       C 10000 C 9000

   ------(no D in 1.csv) D 10000
```

Comment: *file3* is the common lines, and *file4* the diff. (You might like to rename them something more intuititive like that.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one . it works . I showed u a mechanism to search . U can modify to make efficient

```
import csv
    file1 = open("Book1.csv", "r")
    reader1=csv.reader(file1)
    print reader1
    reader1.next()
    file2 = open("Book2.csv", "r")
    reader2=csv.reader(file2)
    reader2.next()
    file3 = open("file3.txt", "w")
    file4 = open("file4.txt", "w")
    file1.seek(0,0)
    file2.seek(0,0)
    list1 = file1.readlines()
    print list1
    list2 = file2.readlines()
    print list2
    d={}
    for j in list2:
        temp=j.split(',')
        print temp
        d[temp[0]]=temp[1]
    print d
    for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
        key = i.split(',')
        try:
            if d[key[0]]:
                print d[key[0]]
                if d[key[0]]==key[1]:
                    file3.write(i)
                    file3.write(j)
                else:
                    file4.write(i)
                    file4.write(j)
        except:
            print key[0],'not in file 2'
            continue
```

Comment: Sundar i tried the above script but still output is not correct